# Kafka Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, apache-kafka

Is there a mailing list / page including all CVEs regarding Apache Kafka and its counterparts?

I am looking for something like [this](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/27453/Apache-Zookeeper.html?vendor_id=45).

Comment: Kafka does not seem to have a similar page. I found this however that could help: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/issues/KAFKA-6706?filter=allopenissues and also you can check Docker, where you can usually find a list of security issues, but for Kafka there is none listed: https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/tags/

Comment: I already had a look at their issue tracker and you can spot some potential security related vulnerabilities by appropriate filtering but, even so, there is not a clear idea on their ranking and impact on the platform (information which CVEs include). Anyway,  seems like Confluent likes to keep an air of secrecy around the topic. Furthermore, I do not think Docker images' security vulnerabilities would have much to do with Kafka's internals. Thanks a lot for your response though!

Comment: Docker vulnerabilities do have to do with the component itself according to this: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/image-scan/#view-docker-security-scanning-results But anyway, none have been reported. Maybe you can suggest to the Kafka team to include a page that lists the vulnerabilities etc.